# OpenCV: scale and convert IplImage data

Tags: image, opencv, scale, image-conversion, 24-bit

I'm totally new in OpenCV so hopefully that's not a too stupid question.

As a result of a OpenCV operation (capturing image data from a device) I get back a IplImage.

Depending on its real size I first have to scale it an next convert it to a plain, raw 24 bit RGB format.

For first operation I guess there is some scaling function available. But how about accessing and converting the raw image data? I could not find anything suitable within IplImage structure - at least I could not identify a member as a pointer to the image data.

Any operation that slowly reads out every songle pixel is not suitable, I have to do that operation very often and therefor need fast access to the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all why do you use `IplImage` instead of `cv::Mat`? It's the best format for saving image.

For your first operation there's function [resize](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20resize%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20dsize,%20double%20fx,%20double%20fy,%20int%20interpolation%29).

To convert it to RGB format (if I'm not mistaken OpenCV by default saves images in BGR format) you can youse [cvtColor](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#void%20cvtColor%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20code,%20int%20dstCn%29) function with code (3'rd parameter) `CV_BGR2RGB`.

Or if you want to take a pointer to image (pixels) data see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899108/opencv-get-pixel-information-from-mat-image).

Comment: @Elmi, plese, read [this documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) carefully.