# How to improve sorting pixels in cvMat?

Tags: c++, sorting, opencv

I am trying to sort pixel values of an image (example 80x20) from lowest to highest.

Below is the some code:

```
bool sortPixel(int first, int second)
{
    return (first < second);
}

    vector<int>vect_sortPixel;
    for(int y=0; y<height; y++)
    {
        for(int x=0; x<width; x++)
        {
            vect_sortPixel.push_back(cvGetReal2D(srcImg, y, x));
            sort(vect_sortPixel.begin(), vect_sortPixel.end(), sortPixel);
        }
    }
```

But it takes quite long time to compute. Any suggestion to reduce the processing time?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you add code for the `sort()` method?

Comment: i'm sorry. the sort is called from (algorithm.h)

Comment: what about using `sort` function in OpenCV? http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=sort#sort

Comment: But it stated "If you want to sort matrix rows or columns lexicographically, you can use STL std::sort generic function with the proper comparison predicate."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use getReal2D. It's quite slow.

Convert image to cv::Mat or Mat. Use its data pointer to get the pixel values. Mat.data() will give you pointer to the original matrix. Use that.

And as far as sorting is concerned, I would advise you to first make an array of all the pixels, then sort it using Merge sort (time complexity O(n log n))

```
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Mat img = imread("filename.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    unsigned char *input = (unsigned char*)(img.data);
    int i,j,r,g,b;
    for(int i = 0;i < img.cols;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j < img.rows;j++){
                b = input[img.cols * j + i] ;
                g = input[img.cols * j+ i + 1];
                r = input[img.cols *j + i +2];
            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Using this you can access pixel values from the main matrix.

**Warning: This is not how you compare it. I'm suggesting that by using something like this, you can access pixel values.**

Mat.data() gives you pointer to the original matrix. This matrix is a 1 D matrix with all the given pixel values.

Image => (x,y,z),(x1,y1,z1), etc..

Mat(original matrix) => x,y,z,x1,y1,z1,...

If you still have some doubts regarding how to extract data from Mat, visit this link [OpenCV get pixel channel value from Mat image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899108/opencv-get-pixel-information-from-mat-image)

and here's a link regarding Merge Sort http://www.cplusplus.happycodings.com/Algorithms/code17.html

Comment: How can I do that? Can you give me some example?

Comment: @Mizuki [Wikipedia's Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) article has some pseudocode. Personally I'd use a Radix or Quick sort, since they're generally faster, although they are more complex to code. Unless your images are really massive though, merge sort should be fine.

Comment: where can I find the Radiz or Quick Sort? Is it available? Thank you for your information. It helps a lot.

Comment: @MizukiKai there's `qsort` in STL. Just google it. And I already told you that `sort` should work fast. Have you done all steps I told you? I'm 100% sure that after doing it your algorithm will be very fast.

Comment: @Froyo this is also a bit slow beceause you use two cycles instead one and `img.cols * j` takes a lot time. Also you even didn't test it because it crashes at first iteration `input[-1] = ?`

Comment: I didn't mean to take this loop. I just suggested that you can access pixel values in this way. sorry if it's misleading. I'll edit.

Comment: So why did you adit your message? Before editing: `Use its data pointer to get the pixel values. Mat.data() will give you pointer to the original matrix. Use that.` Isn't it a suggestion???

Comment: No. It's still there. see. I just suggested him how to use Mat.data

Comment: Why don't you answer my question?

Comment: I haven't removed that statement. It's there. Please see the answer again.

Answer (score 1):

There are few problems in your code:

- As [Froyo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/891373/froyo) already said you use `cvGetReal2D` which is actually not very fast. You have to convert your `cvMat` to `cv::Mat`. To do this there's [cv::Mat constructor](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#mat):

> ```
> // converts old-style CvMat to the new matrix; the data is not copied by default
> Mat(const CvMat* m, bool copyData=false);
> ```

And after this use direct pixels acces as mentioned in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899108/opencv-get-pixel-information-from-mat-image).

- Another problem is that you use `push_back` which actually also not very fast. You know the size of array, so why don't you allocate needed memory at the beginning? Like this:

`vector<int> vect_sortPixel(mat.cols*mat.rows);`

And than just use `vect_sortPixel[i]` to get needed pixel.

- Why do you call `sort` in the loop? You have to call it after loop, when array is already created! Default [STL's sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) should work fast:

> Complexity
>
> Approximately N*logN comparisons on average (where N is
>   last-first). In the worst case, up to N^2, depending on specific
>   sorting algorithm used by library implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I kinda know what to do next. It helps.

Comment: How can I get the pixel just by using vect_sortPixel[i]? I need to push back first right?

Comment: @MizukiKai no! I already told you that `push_back` is slow operation. If you know size of array than it makes sense to allocate needed memory in vector constructor. Do you know what do words `allocate` and `constructor` mean? If no than read [this article](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/).