# How to set a pixel to a value in a cv::Mat object?

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to set a single pixel in the Mat object to a certain value.

How to do it?

I am using openCV 2.1 with visual studio 2010.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV get pixel information from Mat image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899108/opencv-get-pixel-information-from-mat-image)

Comment: There are a ton other posts explaining exactly the same problem

Comment: Not to speak of the actual OpenCV documentation, whose first few paragraphs on `cv::Mat` should cover this.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if you consider it so.

Answer (score 21):

If you are dealing with a uchar (CV_8U) matrix:

```
 mat.at<uchar>(row, column, channel) = val;
```

Comment: Am not able to get this to work.  Can you provide a code which confirms this works?

Answer (score 6):

In fact, there are 4 kinds of methods to get/set a pixel value in a cv::Mat object as described in [the OpenCV tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#performance-difference).

The one @Régis mentioned is called **On-The-Fly RA** in OpenCV tutorial. It's the most convenient but also time-consuming.

Based on the [tutorial's experiment](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#performance-difference), it also lists performance differences in all the 4 methods.

- Efficient Way    79.4717 milliseconds
- Iterator 83.7201 milliseconds
- **On-The-Fly RA**    93.7878 milliseconds
- LUT function 32.5759 milliseconds

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example:

```
vector<cv::Point3f> xyzBuffer;
cv::Mat xyzBuffMat = cv::Mat(307200, 1, CV_32FC3);
for (int i = 0; i < xyzBuffer.size(); i++) {
    xyzBuffMat.at<cv::Vec3f>(i, 1, 0) = xyzBuffer[i].x;
    xyzBuffMat.at<cv::Vec3f>(i, 1, 1) = xyzBuffer[i].y;
    xyzBuffMat.at<cv::Vec3f>(i, 1, 2) = xyzBuffer[i].z;
}
```

Comment: How come you are indexing the column with a 1 instead of a zero?

Comment: The answer isn't correct.
This should be the correct way to set the values:
```xyzBuffMat.at<float>(i, 1, 0) = xyzBuffer[i].x

xyzBuffMat.at<float>(i, 1, 1) = xyzBuffer[i].y 

xyzBuffMat.at<float>(i, 1, 2) = xyzBuffer[i].z```
or 
`xyzBuffMat.at<cv::Vec3f>(i, 1, 0) = xyzBuffer[i]`