# How to get an array or any collection of pixels from video in real time using opencv (Android)

Tags: java, android, opencv, video, pixel

Exacly as in the subject I would like to analyse video from android phone using opencv. How to get the access to the pixels(rgb or similar) while recording a video(there can be slight lag)?

I have downloaded tegra developer pack which has Opencv 2.4.3.2

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest looking in to JAVACV, it uses the opencv bindings to do whatever, but from JAVA! a simple google search would reveal a number of C++ pixel value how to's

The question you posed is very open ended, there are many questions i would ask...so your using opencv....which version? have you tried anything and did it work? how are you implementing opencv for the android? is this for a school project?

more information is good! :-)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I havedownloaded tegra developer pack which has OpenCv 2.4.3.2 included.

Comment: Also, don't forget OpenCV stores things internally as BGR not RGB.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899108/opencv-get-pixel-information-from-mat-image

http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html