# vil_image_view to cv::Mat conversion

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, containers

Can any one suggest me a function which can convert vil_image_view container to a cv::Mat container? I have a confusion over notation of the dimensions, i.e, number of rows & height, number of columns & width

Comment: What is a  vil_image_view container ?

Comment: It is from vxl library, like openCV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have VXL installed in my environment and I think that the best thing to do in your case is to found the correct code by means of trial and error... in my experience reading the documentation is just a part of the solution of the problem.

Having said that, my first guess would be (please remember, I did not test the code):

```
#include <vcl_iostream.h>
#include <vxl_config.h>
#include <vil/vil_rgb.h>
#include <vil/vil_load.h>
#include <vil/vil_image_view.h>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

int main()
{
  vil_image_view<vil_rgb<vxl_byte> > img_src;
  img_src = vil_load("test.png");

  int n_rows = img_src.ni();
  int n_cols = img_src.nj();

  // see http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html#accessing-pixel-intensity-values
  const int OPENCV_RED_INDEX   = 2;
  const int OPENCV_GREEN_INDEX = 1;
  const int OPENCV_BLUE_INDEX  = 0;

  // see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7903042/15485
  cv::Mat img_dst(n_rows, n_cols, CV_8UC3);
  for ( int r = 0; r < n_rows; r++ ) {
    for ( int c = 0; c < n_cols; c++ ) {
        img_dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(r,c)[OPENCV_RED_INDEX  ] = img_src(c,r).r;
        img_dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(r,c)[OPENCV_GREEN_INDEX] = img_src(c,r).g;
        img_dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(r,c)[OPENCV_BLUE_INDEX ] = img_src(c,r).b;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And my second guess would be:

```
#include <vcl_iostream.h>
#include <vxl_config.h>
#include <vil/vil_rgb.h>
#include <vil/vil_load.h>
#include <vil/vil_image_view.h>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

int main()
{
  vil_image_view<vil_rgb<vxl_byte> > img_src;
  img_src = vil_load("test.png");

  int n_rows = img_src.ni();
  int n_cols = img_src.nj();

  // see http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html#accessing-pixel-intensity-values
  const int OPENCV_RED_INDEX   = 2;
  const int OPENCV_GREEN_INDEX = 1;
  const int OPENCV_BLUE_INDEX  = 0;

  // see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7903042/15485
  cv::Mat img_dst(n_rows, n_cols, CV_8UC3);
  for ( int r = 0; r < n_rows; r++ ) {
    for ( int c = 0; c < n_cols; c++ ) {
        img_dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(r,c)[OPENCV_RED_INDEX  ] = img_src(r,c).r;
        img_dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(r,c)[OPENCV_GREEN_INDEX] = img_src(r,c).g;
        img_dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(r,c)[OPENCV_BLUE_INDEX ] = img_src(r,c).b;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should it be 

int n_cols = img_src.ni();
int n_rows = img_src.nj(); ??

Comment: @HN Hello, I see you accepted the answer, thank you. If you have a working code, please update my answer so it will be a reference for future users. Thank you.