# Change pixel in a zero matrix not working correctly

Tags: c++

I try to do a loop over a new zero matrix and change every pixel to white.

```
cv::Mat background = cv::Mat::zeros(frame.rows, frame.cols,frame.type());

for (int i=0; i<frame.rows; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<frame.cols; j++)
    {
        background.at<char>(i,j)=255;
    }
}
```

Normally at the end i have to have a matrix totally white But i don't understand why finally i have this picture:

[image]

Thanks

**EDIT:**
solution:

```
cv::Mat background = cv::Mat::zeros(frame.rows, frame.cols,frame.type());

for (int i=0; i<frame.rows; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<frame.cols; j++)
    {

         Vec3b bgrPixel = Vec3b(255,255,255);
         background.at<Vec3b>(i,j)=bgrPixel;

    //    background.at<char>(i,j)=255;


    }
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: What is expected output ?

Comment: Totally white as you can see on my code.

Comment: Uh you only seem to be setting 1 of 3 (or 4) channels to white. Which to me explains why only 1/3 of the image is white. You probably end up setting all 3 channels for 1/3 of the pixels.

Comment: I don't understand... Can you explain me again ? What i have to do ?
However i saw on the internet that in order to change the pixel, i have to do this.

Comment: Your matrix is made up of i\*j pixels - each pixel is made up of 3 (RGB) or 4 (RGBA) chars (bytes/channels). You are only looping over the first i\*j bytes of the matrix, when you need to be looping over i*j pixels.  I'm guessing whatever type you're passing in as the third argument is the 'pixel type'.  Look here for an example usage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899108/opencv-get-pixel-information-from-mat-image

Edit: made my comment an answer since I think it should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix is made up of i*j pixels - each pixel is made up of 3 (RGB) or 4 (RGBA) chars (bytes/channels). You are only looping over the first i*j bytes of the matrix, when you need to be looping over i*j pixels.  I'm guessing whatever type you're passing in as the third argument is the 'pixel type'.

Look here for an example usage: [OpenCV get pixel channel value from Mat image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899108/opencv-get-pixel-information-from-mat-image)

Comment: It works ! I didn't know that it was not enough what i did. Thank you !