# Read cv::Mat pixel without knowing its pixel format

Tags: opencv

I am aware there are several ways to read and write a pixel value of an OpenCV `cv::Mat` image/matrix.
A common one is the `.at<typename T>(int, int)` method http://opencv.itseez.com/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at .
However, this requires the typename to be known, for instance `.at<double>`.
The same thing applies to more direct pointer access [OpenCV get pixel channel value from Mat image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899108) .

How can I read a pixel value without knowing its type? For instance, it would be ok to receive a more generic `CvScalar` value in return. Efficiency is not an issue, as I would like to read rather small matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know the type, you can use `Mat_<>` type for easy access. If you don't know the type, you can:

- convert the data to `double`, so data won't be truncated in any case
- switch over the number of channels to access correctly the double matrix. Note that you can have at most of 4 channels, since `Scalar` has at most 4 elements.

The following code will convert only the selected element of the source matrix to a double value (with `N` channels).

You get a `Scalar` containing the value at position `row`, `col` in the source matrix.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Scalar valueAt(const Mat& src, int row, int col)
{
    Mat dst;;
    src(Rect(col, row, 1, 1)).convertTo(dst, CV_64F);

    switch (dst.channels())
    {
    case 1: return dst.at<double>(0);
    case 2: return dst.at<Vec2d>(0);
    case 3: return dst.at<Vec3d>(0);
    case 4: return dst.at<Vec4d>(0);
    }

    return Scalar();
}

int main()
{
    Mat m(3, 3, CV_32FC3); // You can use any type here
    randu(m, Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0), Scalar(256, 256, 256, 256));

    Scalar val = valueAt(m, 1, 2);
    cout << val << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty close to what I expected. However, can we avoid the `convertTo` of the full matrix? Maybe by selecting a 1x1 range on `src`?

Answer (score 3):

Kind of. You can construct `cv::Mat_` and provide explicit type for elements, after that you don't have to write element type each time. Quoting `opencv2/core/mat.hpp`

> While Mat is sufficient in most cases, Mat_ can be more convenient if you use a lot of element
>   access operations and if you know matrix type at the compilation time. Note that
>   `Mat::at(int y,int x)` and `Mat_::operator()(int y,int x)` do absolutely the same
>   and run at the same speed, but the latter is certainly shorter.

`Mat_` and `Mat` are very similar. Again quote from mat.hpp:

> The class `Mat_<_Tp>` is a *thin* template wrapper on top of the Mat class. It does not have any
>   extra data fields. Nor this class nor Mat has any virtual methods. Thus, references or pointers to
>   these two classes can be freely but carefully converted one to another.

You can use it like this

```
Mat_<Vec3b> dummy(3,3);
dummy(1, 2)[0] = 10;
dummy(1, 2)[1] = 20;
dummy(1, 2)[2] = 30;
cout << dummy(1, 2) << endl;
```

Why I said 'kind of' in the first place? Because if you want to pass this Mat_ somewhere - you have to specify it's type. Like this:

```
void test(Mat_<Vec3b>& arr) {
    arr(1, 2)[0] = 10;
    arr(1, 2)[1] = 20;
    arr(1, 2)[2] = 30;

    cout << arr(1, 2) << endl;
}
...
Mat_<Vec3b> dummy(3,3);
test(dummy);
```

Technically, you are not specifying your type during a pixel read, but actually you still have to know it and cast the Mat to the appropriate type beforehand.

I guess you can find a way around this using some low-level hacks (for example make a method that reads Mat's type, calculates element size and stride, and then accesses raw data using pointer arithmetic and casting...). But I don't know any 'clean' way to do this using OpenCV's functionality.

Comment: *if you want to pass this Mat_ somewhere - you have to specify it's type.*
Not true. You can pass a `Mat_<whatever>` as a `Mat` parameter (e.g. to a `void test(Mat&)` function) and it will work.

Comment: What will work? Passing is surely possible, but accessing element without specifying type won't work, and that was what I meant

Comment: `void process(const cv::Mat_< float >& arr)` will accept any matrix `cv::Mat`, there is no type checking. If `arr` has `uchar` pixels, the results are wrong.

Comment: I am not sure about this. When I try to pass `Mat` instead of `Mat_<Vec3b>` to `void test(Mat_<Vec3b>& arr)` I get error: `invalid initialization of reference of type ‘cv::Mat_<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3> >&’ from expression of type ‘cv::Mat’`
What compiler are you using?

Comment: @user3896254 gcc 4.6.3 opencv 2.3.1